# Motoman FS100: Missing velocity and effort in joint_states

Tags: ros, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm controlling Yaskawa Motoman  SIA10F (controller: FS100) over ROS.  Previously the `/joint_states` topic had values of `velocity` and `effort` as well as `position`, but now `velocity` and `effort` disappeared (just blank vectors are sent).  I removed some newly-installed packages, but they are still blank.  Can anyone have ideas to fix this issue?

What I am doing to launch the Motoman system is as follows:

```
$ roscore
$ rosparam load `rospack find motoman_sia10f_support`/urdf/sia10f.urdf robot_description
$ rosparam set controller_joint_names "[joint_s, joint_l, joint_e, joint_u, joint_r, joint_b, joint_t]"
$ roslaunch motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_fs100.launch robot_ip:=192.168.12.31
$ rostopic echo /joint_states
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276723/motoman-fs100:-missing-velocity-and-effort-in-joint_states/) by [akihiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/18071/akihiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2017-11-27**:
What do you mean by 'now' ?
Did you do something in your system, like upgrading the packages?

**Comment by [akihiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/18071/akihiko/) on 2017-11-27**:
I added some packages, but now I removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Previously the `/joint_states` topic had values of `velocity` and `effort` as well as `position`, but now `velocity` and `effort` disappeared (just blank vectors are sent).

I believe you are mistaken, because if you are using the [motoman_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver) (which, from the commands you show, I believe you are) then `velocity` and `effort` were never published as part of the `JointState` msgs by the `robot_state` publisher. Those are simply not being populated by the current version of the driver.

See also [ros-industrial/motoman#174](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/issues/174), where this is being tracked and discussed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akihiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/18071/akihiko/) on 2017-11-27**:
Mmm it could be my mistake.  What I'm sure is that I saw a "response" of robot for pushing it.  I thought the response was effort, but it could be a slight change of joint positions.  You should be right as I am using the pure [motoman_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver).  Thanks so much.